# Java "java" command in Windows CMD not working with Swing applications; Error:Main method not found in class

Tags: java, swing, class, cmd, compilation

I am a Java programmer, but recently the "java" command in the Windows CMD stopped working with my Java Swing GUI applications. It works all right with console Java apps, but when I try to run Swing GUI apps with it, it generates this random error:

```
Error:Main method not found in class SFXtest1, please define the main method:
public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX application class must
extend javafx.application.Application
```

I can understand `"Main method not found in class SFXtest1"` but then I already *have* defined the main method in the `.java` file.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: what is the command you wrote in the cmd?

Comment: "java SFXtest1" of course

Comment: problem is that I can't run Swing apps, though i can compile them without any errors

Comment: you're probably missing something in your classpath, since you didn't specify anything in your `java` command.  Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509318/cant-run-swing-from-the-command-line), see if it helps.

Comment: Are you using javafx? Btw - did you compiled your java program before? ``javac SFXtest1.java``

Comment: yes i compiled the Swing app then ran it using "java"

Comment: i compiled it using "javac" in the CMD

Comment: Did you add the static main directly in SFXtest1 and NOT in an inner class, correct? Maybe you could add a subset of SFXtest1 to your question.

Comment: @uraimo yes I added the "public static void main" in the main source file "SFXtest1"

Comment: Can you post the class here or on pastebin?

Comment: so I post the class file, you mean?

Comment: yes, so we can take a look at it

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zajjkaXF

Comment: btw it mmight be a bit confusing because this project i changed its name right now ignore the "NotPong" thing

Comment: Did you paste the .class file? :D

Comment: yes you told me to +)

Comment: could you post the main class source code(.java file) with your question?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2Y8GxhYV